# Apache+Passenger == HAProxy + Mogrel Servers (M/M/C Queue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, thin, mongrel

I recently read a great blog post made by SoundCloud Team. The Article talks about the Software Architecture Evolution.

http://backstage.soundcloud.com/2012/08/evolution-of-soundclouds-architecture/

In the section **"Load distribution and a little queue theory"** Sean Treadway, talks about queue theory and how to better use the queue.

He Wrote:

> We wanted a system that never queued, but if it did queue, the wait
>   time in the queue was minimal. Taking the M/M/c model to the extreme,
>   we asked ourselves “how can we make c as large as possible?”
>
> To do this, we needed to make sure that a single Rails application
>   server never received more than one request at a time
>
> We added HAProxy into our infrastructure, configuring each backend with a maximum connection count > of 1 and added our backend processes across all hosts, to get that wonderful M/M/c reduction in > resident wait time by queuing the HTTP request until any backend process on any host becomes available

Apparently, they are using HAProxy + Rails Servers ( Maybe Mongrel ).
Ok, HAProxy enqueing incoming requests and only dispatching to Mogrel/Thin when it is available.

Maybe could I be completely wrong ;), but Apache + Passenger do the same thing, right ?
One queue ( Apache handling incoming requests ) and C Workers ( Child Process )

Answer (score 0):

Apache + Passenger does indeed distribute incoming requests to rack backends (unless the requests refer to static resources, which apache handles by itself).

This model works as long as one single host can run all (!) the rack instances. When you need more instances, apache can't handle it anymore and you would have to put something on top (often HAProxy). But then, apache's functionality is much bigger than just serving rack based apps. So it makes sense to replace it with something more lightweight (for example nginx), especially because you deploy it once for every host you have.

I hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks @mosch. "when you need more instances, apache can't handle it anymore and you would have to put something on top" means that apache will purge incoming requests when there is no available child in passenger Pool ? Did apache do not enqueue ?

Comment: What I meant is that I don't know of a way to make apache distribute incoming requests to different hosts. Passenger is handling this for a single host and a few rack apps (meaning that the passenger pool is on the local host) but it doesn't relay to different hosts (AFAIK).